# Ctypes pointer on element in ctypes array

Tags: python, ctypes

Is there a way to get a pointer to an element in the middle of an ctypes array?
Example:

```
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./lib.so')
arr = (ctypes.c_int32 * 100)()
lib.foo(arr)
```

Now I don't want to call `foo` with a pointer to the first element of `arr`, but on the 10th. That would be equivalent to C notation `&arr[9]`:

```
lib.foo(&arr[9])
```

Is there a smart way to do this?

Comment: How does the (*C*) `foo` function declaration looks like?

Comment: In this example it could be `void foo(int32_t *arr)`

Comment: Ok, and inside the func, I imagine there's some processing taking place. That processing involves accessing the elements of the array (passed as a pointer). ?How does the function when to stop? meaning that If i pass a 100 values array how does it know not to access 101th element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`byref` has an optional parameter to add a byte offset to the address.

**test.dll (Windows)**

```
__declspec(dllexport) int foo(int* arr)
{
    return *arr;
}
```

Example:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> lib = CDLL('test')
>>> arr = (c_int * 100)(*range(100))
>>> arr[9]
9
>>> lib.foo(arr)
0
>>> lib.foo(byref(arr,sizeof(c_int) * 9))
9
```